# Reformulation of riemann zeta

Tags: number-theory, riemann-zeta, zeta-functions, riemann-hypothesis

Does this extend to $\mathbb{C}$?

$\displaystyle ζ(x) = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{ 1}{\lfloor t\rfloor ^x} dt$, where for $0 \leq t < 1$ we say that $\lfloor t \rfloor = 1$.

Comment: My gut feel is that we can use the Fourier definition of floor(x) to extend this to C

Comment: I might also guess that you secretly want the integral to go from $1$ to $\infty$? (If that's wrong, then I over-edited the question)

Comment: 0 to infinity where we assume the discontinuity at floor(0) is equal to 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $\Re(x) > 1$, this integral converges. Further, this integral converges to exactly the regular Riemann zeta function. Thus an analytic continuation of the regular Riemann zeta is an analytic continuation of this function.

**[Given the clarification]**:

Instead of converging to the regular Riemann zeta function, this zeta function is exactly the regular Riemann zeta function $+1$ (for the bit between $0$ and $1$), and thus we still get our continuation from the regular Riemann zeta function.

Comment: Can you use the Fourier series of this function to explore the Riemann zeta function then?

Comment: @frogeyedpeas: It might be possible, but I see a few problems that would come up. In particular, we often like Fourier series for analytic continuations because we get access to Poisson summation. But Poisson summation requires more than just periodicity: it also requires continuous differentiability, or bounded variation, or L^1 with rapid decay. But a sum across the floor function is not of bounded variation or differentiable. Perhaps you could use a more sophisticated view of Poisson summation, but I don't know about that.